# MVC routing - exceptions if I put parameter id

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to put the product id in the url in (ProductDetails page) with MVC routing.
Without the id parameter everything is working fine, but if I put the id, I get this exception.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SubCategories(System.String, Int32, System.String, System.String)' in 'OnlineCarStore.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SubCategories(System.String, Int32, System.String, System.String)' in 'OnlineCarStore.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

This is what I have in the view:

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("ProductDetails", "Product" , new {supplierName = c.SupplierName.Replace(" ", "-"), code = productCode, name = name.Replace("---", "-"), prodId=c.ProductId })" id="link">
     Details
  </a>
```

and in the controller:

```
 [Route("{supplierName}/{code}/{name}/{prodId}")]
 public ActionResult ProductDetails(string supplierName, string code, string name, string prodId)
 {...}
```

Can you please advise what can be the problem? As I said without the prodId parameter everything is fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message shows your calling the `SubCategories` method. What is the signature and `Route` attribute applied to that method (its matching that one first)?

Comment: I use this route at Subcategories method:  [Route("{selected}/{category}/{id}/{engineId}")]
        public ActionResult SubCategories(string selected, int id, string category, string engineId)
        {

Comment: You need to edit you question with the relevant details. That is identical to your route on the `ProductDetails` method (i.e. it contains 4 segments) You need to distinguish them - e.g. `[Route("Product/ProductDetails/{supplierName}/{code}/{name}/{prodId}")]`

Comment: But in the url I should not show the the controller and the actin method name :Product/ProductDetails. This is the reason why I put it this way the routes

Comment: You need something to distinguish your routes!

Comment: @Orsi Yep, your site is getting confused by your routes with no distinguishing features. If you want 2 (or more) routes to be structured as `yourdomain.com/{string}/{string}/{string}/{int}` then you maybe need one route config entry to point requests to a controller action that handles the processing of the params, works out where it should go then pushes on to the relevant controller/action.